# Changing the Sending IP and Port of UDP Packet in Java

Tags: java, android, udp, ip, port

I am working on a project for androids/computers have p2p talking, and we are experimenting with hole-punching in order to get through the wifi's firewall.  However the wifi needs to UDP packet needs to look like it is coming from the same machine that the initial Packet was sent to.  Using netcat (and choosing which port to send from) from the same machine we can send information back into the computer.  However if we are coming from a different device we need to appear as though we have the same IP address, and port.  I was wondering if you can easily specify the Sending IP and Port of the packet?  I was thinking of using [DatagramPacket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html), but didn't find any methods that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that from within Java. You can do it with Java plus one of the several Jpcaps in existence, but be aware it's a JNI library with all the risks that entails.

Comment: What class/method allows you do that? I was looking over the documentation and I could not find anything.

Comment: @Jbad26 The whole of Jpcap allows you to do that. You can synthesize entire IP packets.